# Data Binding expression with exception handling

Tags: android, reflection, exception, android-databinding

How to handle an Exception being thrown by the method that I call in the binding expression?

For example,

```
android:someAttribute="@{myClass.getField(`myField`)}"
```

Method `getField()` throws `NoSuchFieldException` and the compiler complains about unhandled exception in the generated code.

Comment: catch the exception and return a default value?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by "handling".